# How does modular code work in Go?

Tags: module, compilation, package, projects-and-solutions, go

Not having come from a C/compiled languages background, I'm finding it hard to get to grips with using Go's packages mechanism to create modular code.

In Python, to import a module and get access to it's functions and whatnot, it's a simple case of

```
import foo
```

where foo.py is the name of the module you want to import in the same directory. Otherwise you can add an empty `__init__.py` into a subfolder and access the modules via

```
from subfolder import foo
```

You can then access functions by simply referencing them through the module name, e.g. `y = foo.bar(y)`. This makes it easy to separate logical pieces of code from one another.

---

In Go however, you specify the package name in the source file itself, e.g.

```
package foo
```

at the top of the 'foo' module, which you can then supposedly import through

```
import (
        "foo"
              )
```

and then refer to it through that, i.e. `y := foo.Bar(x)` . But what I can't wrap my head around is how this works in practice. The relevant docs on golang.org seem terse, and directed to people with more (any) experience using makefiles and compilers.

Can someone please clearly explain how you are meant to modularise your code in Go, the right project structure to do so, and how the compilation process works?

Comment: I will reply with a link to an example repository showing this hole deal in action. https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-example-multipkg

Hope that helps a bit. Apologies for the shameless self-plug of my github thingy, but this works better than replicating it all here on SO.

Comment: For Go Modules (new in Go 1.11), many of the same answers still apply, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314494/11210494) covers this question a bit more for Go modules.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wiki answer,  please feel free to add/edit.

### Modularization

1. Multiple files in the same package

   - This is just what it sounds like.  A bunch of files in the same directory that all start with the same `package <name>` directive means that they are treated as one big set of code by Go.  You can transparently call functions in `a.go` from `b.go`.  This is mostly for the benefit of code organization.
   - A fictional example would be a "blog" package might be laid out with `blog.go` (the main file), `entry.go`, and `server.go`.  It's up to you.  While you could write a blog package in one big file, that tends to affect readability.
2. Multiple packages

   - The standard library is done this way.  Basically you create modules and optionally install them into `$GOROOT`.  Any program you write can `import "<name>"` and then call `<name>.someFunction()`
   - In practice any standalone or shared components should be compiled into packages.  Back to the blog package above, If you wanted to add a news feed, you could refactor server.go into a package.  Then both `blog.go` and `news.go` would both `import "server"`.

### Compilation

I currently use gomake with Makefiles.  The Go installation comes with some great include files for make that simplify the creation of a package or a command.  It's not hard and the best way to get up to speed with these is to just look at sample makefiles from open source projects and read ["How to Write Go Code"](http://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: Ok, that's really cleared a lot of it up, thanks! But do you have to redeclare imports for every file in the package?

Comment: Probably, but the compiler will tell you when you are missing or don't need an import.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the package organisation, Like pip in python, use dep https://github.com/golang/dep for go package management. if you use it on existing go package it will automatically build the dependency tree with versions for all the packages being used. when shifting to production server, dep ensure will use Gopkg.toml to install all the required packages.
Just use dep ensure -add , other commands for dep are:

```
Commands:

    init     Set up a new Go project, or migrate an existing one
    status   Report the status of the project's dependencies
    ensure   Ensure a dependency is safely vendored in the project
    version  Show the dep version information
    check    Check if imports, Gopkg.toml, and Gopkg.lock are in sync

 Examples:
    dep init                               set up a new project
    dep ensure                             install the project's dependencies
    dep ensure -update                     update the locked versions of all dependencies
    dep ensure -add github.com/pkg/errors  add a dependency to the project
```