# Organize local code in packages using Go modules

Tags: go, go-modules, go-packages

I can not find a way to factor out some code from `main.go` into a local package when using Go modules (go version >= 1.11) outside of `$GOPATH`.

I am not importing any external dependencies that need to be included into `go.mod`, I am just trying to organize locally the source code of this Go module.

The file `main.go`:

```golang
package main

// this import does not work
import "./stuff"

func main() {
    stuff.PrintBaz()
}
```

The file `./stuff/bar.go` (pretending to be a local package):

```golang
package stuff

import "log"

type Bar struct {
    Baz int
}

func PrintBaz() {
    baz := Bar{42}
    log.Printf("Bar struct: %v", baz)
}
```

The file `go.mod` (command `go mod init foo`):

```
module foo

go 1.12
```

When executing `go run main.go`:

- If I `import "./stuff"`, then I see `build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path _/home/<PATH_TO>/fooprj/stuff`.
- If I `import "stuff"`, then I see `build command-line-arguments: cannot load stuff: cannot find module providing package stuff`.
- If I `import stuff "./stuff"` with a package alias, then I see again: `build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path _/home/<PATH_TO>/fooprj/stuff`.

I can not find a way to make local packages work with go modules.

- What's wrong with the code above?
- How can I import local packages into other Go code inside a project defined with Go modules (file `go.mod`)?

Comment: If you want to develop *multiple* modules in the same project, you will have to wait for Go 1.18/1.19, and the notion of [Go workspace mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68420398/6309).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

First you have to choose a name for your project and write it to go.mod file. This name belongs to root directory of the project. Each new package you create must be located inside its own subdirectory and its name should match directory name.

go.mod:

```
module myprojectname
```

or (preferred way, see @thepudd's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314494/11210494) for details)

```
module github.com/myname/myprojectname
```

Then import your project's packages like:

```
import myprojectname/stuff
```

or

```
import github.com/myname/myprojectname/stuff
```

Files of package `stuff` should be located inside project's `stuff` directory. You name these files as you like.

Also it's possible to create deeper project structure. For instance, you decided to separate source code files from other ones (like app configs, docker files, static files, etc...). Let's move `stuff` directory inside `pkg`, every go file inside `pkg/stuff` still have `stuff` package name. To import stuff package just write:

```
import myprojectname/pkg/stuff
```

Nothing stops you from creating more levels in the hierarchy like `github.com/myuser/myprojectname/pkg/db/provider/postgresql`, where:

- `github.com/myuser/myprojectname` - project name.
- `postgresql` - package name.
- `pkg/db/provider/postgresql` - path to the package relative to project's root.

You can read more about go modules here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Check out this repository to get useful information about various patterns used in project organizing: https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout If you go inside `pkg` directory you will find out which open source projects use `pkg` directory in their structure.

Comment: Do you normally have your `go.mod`, `go.sum`, and `main.go` files in the root directory of your repo?

Comment: `go.mod` and `go.sum` - yes. `main.go` is entry point to your program. If you have single entry point just place it in root directory, otherwise check `cmd` directory README.md file in https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

Comment: Is the layout provided in the repo still way to go? Don't go modules change that?

Comment: Go modules do not define project layout structure, you can use go modules with any layout of your choice. You can read more about go modules here https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#modules

Comment: Defining your module in the `go.mod` as `module myprojectname` (instead of `module github.com/myname/myproject`) is a bit dangerous, and will most likely fail later in a way that surprises you. It is almost always better to use the full path including a hostname of where you intend to publish it eventually, or pick as hostname as if it will be published someday  (unless you are doing something throwaway like a quick test that starts `go mod init tempmod` and you intend to delete the module soon). Some more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314494/11210494).

Comment: @typical182 agreed. I added a notice to your answer.

Comment: For some people (like myself), this could be the key "_Files of package stuff should be located inside project's `stuff` directory_". Package import didn't work unless you put the go files related to stuff in a dir.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is literally the only one I found that makes sense for local package organisation.

Answer (score 112):

#### Module structure

The most common and easiest approach is:

- Use a single `go.mod` per repository, and
- Place the single `go.mod` file in the repository root, and
- Use the repository name as the module path declared in the `module` line in the `go.mod`

  - (If you are using a [custom import path](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) such as `me.io/mymod` rather than using a VCS host based import path, then you would use the custom import path instead of the repository name in your `go.mod`).

For example, if your repo is `github.com/my/repo`, then you would place a single `go.mod` in the repo root, with the first line reading `module github.com/my/repo`. That can be created by `cd`'ing to the repo root and running `go mod init github.com/my/repo`. When working with the repo locally, the `repo` directory can be located wherever is convenient on your filesystem. (If you do not have a repo, see below).

Following this helps you stay on the happy path with modules, and it avoids multiple subtleties.

Russ Cox commented in [#26664](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26664#issuecomment-455232444):

> For all but power users, you probably want to adopt the usual convention that one repo = one module. It's important for long-term evolution of code storage options that a repo *can* contain multiple modules, but it's almost certainly not something you want to do by default.

There is much more about multi-module repositories in the ["Multi-module Repositories"](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#faqs--multi-module-repositories) FAQ section on the modules wiki. Those 6 or so FAQs in that section should be read in their entirety by anyone considering veering off the recommendation above.

#### Arranging packages within a module

Once you have set up your `go.mod`, you can arrange your packages in directories however you see fit in directories underneath the directory containing the `go.mod`, as well as in the directory with the `go.mod`. Three good articles about how to arrange your code in packages:

- https://rakyll.org/style-packages/
- https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1#.ds38va3pp
- https://www.goinggo.net/2017/02/design-philosophy-on-packaging.html

Those articles are classics that pre-date the introduction of modules, but the philosophies in them still apply to how to arrange your packages within a module.

#### Importing other packages in the same module

When importing another package with modules, you always use the full path including the module path. This is true even when importing another package in the same module. For example, if a module declared its identity in its `go.mod` as module `github.com/my/repo`, and you had this organization:

```
repo/
├── go.mod      <<<<< Note go.mod is located in repo root
├── pkg1
│   └── pkg1.go
└── pkg2
    └── pkg2.go
```

Then `pkg1` would import its peer package as `import "github.com/my/repo/pkg2"`. Note that you **cannot** use relative import paths like `import "../pkg2"` or `import "./subpkg"`. (This is part of what OP hit above with `import "./stuff"`).

#### Modules vs. repositories vs. packages vs. import paths

A Go module is a collection of related Go packages that are versioned together as a single unit. Modules record precise dependency requirements and create reproducible builds.

Summarizing the relationship between repositories, modules, and packages:

- A *repository* contains one or more Go *modules* (most often exactly one module in the repository root).
- Each module contains one or more Go *packages*.
- Each package consists of one or more Go *source files* that all reside in a *single directory*.
- Each Go source code file:

  - declares its own package with a `package foo` statement, which must be consistent for all Go files in a single package directory.
  - automatically has access to other Go source code in the same package, without explicitly importing its own package.
  - imports code from another package via an *import path* supplied in an import statement such as `import "github.com/my/repo/pkg1"`. The import path always starts with the module path of that package, regardless of whether that package is in the same module or a different module.

A single module can be used to build multiple executable binaries, but the `func main() {...}` entry point for each binary must be in its own `package main`, with each `package main` in a distinct directory.

#### Local-only modules

You can create, build and run modules without ever publishing them or placing them on a VCS server.

A module is defined by a tree of Go source files with a `go.mod` file in the tree's root directory, so you can pick a directory on your local filesystem to serve as the root of your module and place your `go.mod` there. Everything described above still applies, except there does not need to be a repo.

For example:

```
some-directory/
├── go.mod     <<<< go.mod at module root declaring 'module example.com/foo'
├── pkg1
│   └── pkg1.go
└── pkg2
    └── pkg2.go
```

If the module path in the first line of that `go.mod` reads `module example.com/foo`, then `pkg1` would import its peer package as `import "example.com/foo/pkg2"`.

Of course, you can start with a local-only module without a repo, then later start tracking it in a local repo or publish it to a VCS server.

Even for local-only modules, it is a good idea to give the module a globally unique name, such as `go mod init my.org/foo`, or `go mod init github.com/some/repo` as if it will be published someday, even if that repo does not yet exist. (If you are in a hurry, it is possible to use a shorter module name without a dot or leading hostname component, such as `go mod init temp` or `go mod init m`, but it won’t be fetchable by the `go` command, and you run the risk of colliding with a current or future standard library package or otherwise seeing confusing error messages later).

If you have multiple local modules, you can point them at each other via [`replace` directives](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) or via the Go 1.18+ [workspace](https://go.dev/blog/get-familiar-with-workspaces) feature, though those are more complex workflows than placing everything for a given project in a single module.

#### Next steps

If you are new to Go modules, it is worthwhile to go through the official ["Create a Go Module"](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module) tutorial from the Go project. This will likely save you time overall.

If you are stuck right now with an error message related to modules or import paths, there's a very good chance the error will make much more sense after completing the tutorial.

Comment: Thats the best explanation i saw on that subject, 
Thanks

Comment: In case TLDR. The key point from the answer is: `When importing another package with modules, you always use the full path including the module path. This is true even when importing another package in the same module.`

Comment: If you are hosting everything yourself, including GIT, and want to split modules into separate repos, I wrote up some [notes](https://gist.github.com/jimsnab/c6e3f9b8ccdd371914e8e33e92474b24).

Comment: is it a type? the pkg2 will have pkg2.go right? @typical182

Comment: Hi @Yash Tibrewal, that was indeed a typo. Fixed now. Thanks! (Also, FWIW, there does not need to be a direct relationship between the name of the files vs. the name of the package or directory... but that example is clearer without the typo ;-)