# Can I have multiple packages inside a single go module? How?

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a Go module whose name is 'tatata'. It is only developed in my machine and thus it does not contain any path to any URL in the module name.

If I have only one `main` package in my module it works correctly.
However, if I create two packages in the module, I am experiencing some problems.

This is the tree:

```
./|
  |- go.mod
  |-src
     |- main
     |   | - main.go
     |
     |- api
         | - api.go
```

The content of the files:

`go.mod`

```
module tatata

go 1.13
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "tatata/api"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello world")
  api.Test1()
}
```

`api.go`

```
package api

import "fmt"
func Test1() {
   fmt.Println("Testing API")
}
```

When I try to build, I issue `go build ./src/main` and I get the following error: 
`build tatata/src/main: cannot load tatata/api: malformed module path "tatata/api": missing dot in first path element`

Now, if I try to put a dummy dot, like renaming the module to `tatata.com` I get the error `build tatata.com/src/main: cannot load tatata.com/api: cannot find module providing package tatata.com/api` as obviously my package/module is not available in that URL.

`GOPATH` is empty, i.e. not set.

Questions:

a) What is the right way, i.e. naming of modules and imports when using multiple packages inside a single Go module?

b) Is it impossible to have a Go module without dots in its name?!

c) Can you point me to any working example that has a building set-up with a single go module and multiple packages in the module?

Comment: You are missing the src segment: `import "tatata.com/src/api"`.

Comment: Start by removing the `src` folder. Such stuff does not belong into a module. And would make your import path valid.

Comment: There is a good overview of how to structure your module, packages, and files here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314494/11210494

Answer (score 12):

> Can I have multiple packages inside a single go module?

Yes, of course.

> How?

You have to do nothing, it just works.

(Your problem is: You try to import your api package by a wrong name.
Import paths inside a module are of the form `<modulename>/<relative-filepath-from-module-root>`.)

Comment: Which means the import should have been: 
import "tatata/src/api"

Comment: The import statement format is different if the package is inside a directory and not in the same directory where module's go.mod file is present then I found following import format works import ( <packageName> <moduleName>/<directoryName>). E.g. To use stringutils (which is inside directory string) in the module github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils.  Use import ( stringutils  "github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/string")

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many package as you want in a single module, have a look here: https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/

The only constraint is that you cane have a single package for every folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
The `go.mod` file has to be in the folder that contains the packages. In my case it was in the parent of that folder.
Now working.